# Can you send variables from python to swift?

Tags: python, ios, swift, file, synchronization

Ok, I am very new to python and am only about to start swift. I am looking for a way to save a variable in python and use it in swift.

I have never coded in swift so please give me an example.

I am writing background code I want to run behind swift and need to send strings from swift to inputs in python.

I also need to sync python variables to swift.

I am not even sure this is possible so tell me if it isn't.

I do not care if I need to send files.

Comment: This question is way too broad to be considered on topic here. You should read the [help/on-topic] and [ask] help pages to learn how to ask high-quality, on topic questions here. Moreover, without showing at least some research effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: how would I do that? please use code! I don't mind piping code through objective c to other languages and then to swift. I just need the data. – 
  
pickle.dump(cash, open(code+"a.dat", "wb")) – 
 
Using code and cash as pre-existing variables, this python code creates a file when pickle is imported. – 
   
could I load that data in swift?

Comment: These are separate systems that can't directly interoperate (say the way C, Objective C and Swift can). You just need these 2 programs, and use the same set of techniques as if you had a client that connects to a server. If you want to send some data, you serialize it to some common shared format (e.g. JSON, YAML, XML, etc. but not Pickle, which is pretty Python-specific), and you send that over some communication mechanism (like XPC, sockets, pipes, etc.). On the other side, you serialize that data, and use it however you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that interests me a lot.
However it is not as easy or as practical as you may think.

https://betterprogramming.pub/from-swift-import-python-f2fc2a997d4

here is an example that allows you to execute a python script in your swift app.

There really is not way to fully integrate the two where you are able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you are asking.

You can build apps that have part of their code in Objective-C and part in Swift, and share variables between the code.

You can't build apps that contain both Swift and Python code. Python is an interpreted language and Swift is compiled.

You could create command line commands in both languages that pass options to each other and pipe data to each other; you could pass files between Swift and Python, but that's about the extent of it.

Comment: how would I do that? please use code! I don't mind piping code through objective c to other languages and then to swift. I just need the data.

Comment: pickle.dump(cash, open(code+"a.dat", "wb"))

Comment: Using code and cash as pre-existing variables, this python code creates a file when pickle is imported.

Comment: could I load that data in swift?

Comment: Objective-C has the same issues as Swift. It won’t help. Python and Swift/Objective-C/C++ code cannot be built into a single app. You need to use techniques that let two apps/processes communicate with each other. I don’t know Python, so I can’t help with that side of things.